# How to store files of size 50 to 100MB(max) on SQL server to be able to retrieve them faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-c++, storage, varchar

I currently store files in `varchar(max)`  data type in a table in SQL server. I retrieve them as chunks by using WBXML parsing. However, this is time consuming for large files. For example, a file of size 60MB it takes very long, about 7-8 minutes for extracting.
Is there an efficient way either to retrieve it faster having the current data type or should I switch to using some other data type for storing and retrieving the file?

Comment: Do you need to store these in the database? You should be using varbinary(max) instead of varchar(max). Filestream might be an option for you. Also, maybe just storing the file and disc and the filename in sql is another option. There are number of ways you can store files.

Comment: Thanks!.ok yes, I need to store the file in the database only. I just started looking into Filestream option..

Comment: Depending on the sql version you have you can use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx sql 2014 and beyond

Comment: Oh ok thanks. For my requirements, I think FileStream will be sufficient as I will only be using it ocassionally for pushing files to mobile devices. I use SQL Server 2012.